# Python framework for a beginner

Tags: python, frameworks, web

I am new to python and only have read the Byte of Python ebook, but want to move to the web. I am tired of being a CMS tweaker and after I tried python, ruby and php, the python language makes more sense (if that makes any "sense" for the real programmers). I heard a lot of good things about Django, Pyramid, etc, but I dont want to pick the most used or the one with the most magic. Instead I was thinking about one that could "teach" me python along the way. My plan is to rebuild my portfolio using python and a framework and also benefit my python learning along the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel like this isn't really an appropriate question for SO, as there are no answers, merely suggestions. Still, my two cents: Django is great, and IMHO by far the easiest to use. That being said, while a great deal of magic was removed in previous upgrades, it is still quite a large framework. You might want to try the microframework [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)--it's feature set is very minimal, which means you'll have to do a lot yourself, or use various plugins to get the same functionality as Django when it comes to form validation, etc.

Comment: While this is mostly off topic here, I would say that using a framework alone is not a great way to learn a language. Make sure you supplement your web building with other small programming projects as well.

Answer (score 3):

Something lightweight/minimal like [web.py](http://webpy.org/) or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is IMO a much better place to start than Django if your focus is on learning and avoiding "magic" (I have used all three).

You may have to wire up your own DB/persistence/ORM layer and even a templating system (web.py), but this will help you understand what is going on under the hood - there is documentation for both frameworks that walks you through this so dont worry.

You should also learn about concepts like [WSGI](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial)/middleware and [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) if they are new to you.

If you really want to learn from the core you can just straight-up write a plain WSGI/CGI app and wire up your components:

- URL routing
- Database persistence/ORM
- HTML Templating System
- Any other middleware

If this is too difficult, you might want to come back to it later after playing with a more "automatic" framework like web.py or flask. Similarly if you find even those frameworks to be too difficult/minimal to use, then just start with Django (which has excellent documentation/tutorials); there is a lot of automatic "magic", but you just need to build familiarity with the domain of web development; all concepts translate pretty easily between different frameworks

Answer (score 2):

Learning Python is a great idea; however, it will be an effort at the same time.

Work through the Python tutorial over at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/ before diving into one of the many web frameworks.

I can personally recommend Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/) but you will require a solid foundation of Python before understanding its design/principles.